# How to expand a cell in a Syncfusion Angular Grid?

Tags: angular, grid, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion GirdComponent in my project and instead of using command column, I want to have a column with just a toggle button for each row and when I click on the button the cell expands horizontally and other buttons appear - and I want just that cell expands not the whole column- and with the second click the cell goes back to it's first state. I tried adding another css class to the td element (parent of the toggle button) and in that class I give a higher width but it doesn't change. 
is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **detailTemplate** feature of Grid component to show toggle button on each row which will expand the row horizontally.

[Demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/grid/detail-template)

And By default grid does not expand in the cell level but cells can be expanded according the requirements. Please refer to the below tree grid demo,

Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/treegrid/columntemplate

please get back to us with more details if you need any further assistance.